# What is this small vent?

Tags: kia, vents, climate-control, dashboard

I own a kia and noticed this vent as part of the dash around the climate control. I looked in the user manual but there is no labels attached to it.

Does anyone know what it's for?
[image: image of vent]

Thanks

Comment: I would bet it's to tell the temperature, but who knows.

Comment: bluetooth mic i think

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: If it were a temperature sensor, shouldn't there be a second one on the right , since the car has separate temperature controls for left and right? (And would it make sense to have them almost in the middle?)

Comment: @Ben ... could be ... most I've seen are above, though, so it will pick up the driver's voice better (more direct shot). I really don't know ... I bet it would be in the owner's manual, though ... ;-)

Comment: It's not the Bluetooth mic, that is clearly labelled in the manual I thought the same. I honestly cannot see it in the manual. I have looked through all related to this section of the car

Comment: What year and model?

Comment: Looking online, I'll bet it has something to do with the "Clean Air" system Kia has in their vehicles (and which is clearly marked above the temp display). This system provides ionization and cleaning of the air in the cabin. I don't know how the vent would assist or make it work, but I see it on different Clean Air systems in pictures on the internet.

Comment: I looked it up as i have similar in my car it holds the interior temp sensor as @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 suggested. give the make and model pull the trim and check the wire colors to confirm. if someone has a wiring diagram.

Comment: @Jason C Kia cee'd estate, model 3, 1.6 diesel

Comment: @Ben ... if you looked it up, throw an answer down, brother!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an interior temperature sensor for cars with automatic A/C.

This is on my car, a Mitsubishi Lancer it's not in the same location but it serves the same purpose.

[image]

[image]